# Changing value of data in pandas using if

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that I need to change some values in based on 2 other values. Normally i would use if statements but as we all know pandas is not that easy to do that with.

but how can I now change `Cat_Tier_2` to wireless or corded etc based on the word wireless or corded in the description for that line only?

```
Name                                                      x brand mouse
Description                                               I am a wireless mouse
Cat_Tier_1                                                Peripherals
Cat_Tier_2                                                Mouse
```

So I can change `Cat_Tier_1` to mouse by

```
df["Cat_Tier_1"] = df["Cat_Tier_1"].str.replace("Peripherals", "Mouse")
```

using pandas I cant use the good old `if` statements e.g

```
if "wireless" in df["Description"]:
  df["Cat_Tier_2"].str.replace("Mouse", "Wireless")
elif "corded" in df["Description"]:
  df["Cat_Tier_2"].str.replace("Mouse", "Corded")
else:
  pass
```

Comment: Are you sure about that .str added between the object and the method call?

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO yup im sure.. Thats what the documentation asks for

Comment: Oh, sorry, the dataframe isn't already made of strings. My fault.

Comment: do yuo need replace subtring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what your question asks:

```py
df.loc[df.Description.str.contains('wireless'), 'Cat_Tier_2'] = 'wireless'
df.loc[df.Description.str.contains('corded'), 'Cat_Tier_2'] = 'corded'
```

Input:

```
            Name            Description   Cat_Tier_1 Cat_Tier_2
0  x brand mouse  I am a wireless mouse  Peripherals      Mouse
```

Output:

```
            Name            Description   Cat_Tier_1 Cat_Tier_2
0  x brand mouse  I am a wireless mouse  Peripherals   wireless
```

**UPDATE**:

To decide whether it's a mouse based on the presence of `mouse` in `Description`, you can do this:

```py
isMouse = df.Description.str.lower().str.contains('mouse')
for mouseType in ['wireless', 'corded']:
    df.loc[isMouse & df.Description.str.contains(mouseType), 'Cat_Tier_2'] = mouseType
```

Comment: I see what your doing here but if i have say `name: wireless router, description: i'm a wireless router of 2.5g, Cat_Tier_1: router Cat_Tier_2: xyz` the xyz will then turn to wireless as its in the description

Comment: What final value would you want for `Cat_Tier_2` in the example in your comment?

Comment: im aiming only to have the `wireless` or `corded` on if the `cat_Tier_1` is `mouse` and the description contains `wireless or corded` for that mouse item only

Comment: In your original question, 'mouse' was only mentioned in `name` and `Description`, not in `Cat_Tier_1`. Anyway, please see my updated answer which gets the desired result for the example in your comment (wireless router) and hopefully is close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for filter only matched rows by condition in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if need replace substring:

```
m1 = df["Description"].str.contains('wireless')
m2 = df["Description"].str.contains('corded')

df.loc[m1, "Cat_Tier_2"] = df.loc[m1, "Cat_Tier_2"].str.replace("Mouse", "Wireless")
df.loc[m2, "Cat_Tier_2"] = df.loc[m2, "Cat_Tier_2"].str.replace("Mouse", "Corded")
```

Comment: unfortunately that's not working the `Cat_Tier_2` stays the same

Comment: @Shaggy89 - Do you need replace substrings? Or not?

Comment: there is no substring as far as i can tell

Comment: @Shaggy89 - I ask becasue `.str.replace("Mouse", "Corded")` is for replace substring `Mouse` like `Mouse aaa` to `Corded aaa`

Comment: think of it as a category and sub-category. Mouse is the category and wireless is the sub category. once this work the CSV will be imported into WordPress

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question? If not, please consider marking on of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can deal with that.

If you still want to use your if-else or maybe in the future you want to build complex logic to apply to columns one of the ways is pandas `apply` where you can pass columns and functions you want to apply, for example:

```
def func(value):
  new_val = None
  if "wireless" in value:
    new_val = value.replace("Mouse", "Wireless")
  elif "corded" in value:
    new_val = value.replace("Mouse", "Corded")
  else:
    new_val = value

  return new_val
```

```
df['Cat_Tier_2'] = df['Description'].apply(func)
```

but you need this if you have very complex logic. This problem can be fixed with a more simple approach with `loc` like jezrael supposed.

Comment: hahaha that changed EVERYTHING from `Cat_Tier_2` to its `Description` all 6881 lines

Comment: maybe I couldnt understand fully your question. can you tell me more details? Thanks

Comment: it only need to change from `Cat_Tier_2` to wireless if `wireless` is in the description of only that line